# What would have been if $\sqrt{-1}$ were named differently?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

Everyone here knows $\sqrt{-1}$ is called the imaginary unit. If, suppose we are doing a calculation regarding a physical situation and some of the solutions at the end turn out to be "imaginary" and some are real then we reject the imaginary ones without even giving them a second thought $\textbf{just because they were imaginary}$ (at least I was told to do like this). But the other real solutions are given a thought about why we are rejecting them before rejecting all the ones not physically realizable.

Now, suppose we did not have given this name "imaginary" then people would surely have given at least some thought before rejecting them. One case where I encountered a "purely imaginary" (not complex) solution being accepted is in the calculation of spacetime interval in general relativity to classify them as space-like, time-like or null-like. It sure has a physical significance in GR. But, in general, how could we always say complex solutions solve no physical situation. Let me give you an example.

Say, we are calculating where will maximum bending occur in a simply supported beam given a force distribution on it. The beam is of length $5$ (from $x=0$ to $x=5$). And suppose we get solutions as $x=\{-1,\  3,\ 1-i,\ 1+i\}$. From these solutions, we will reject $x=-1$ as it lies outside the beam but on what basis will we reject the complex solutions if they were not given the name "imaginary". The only reason I have to reject the complex solutions is that the solution $x=3$ solves the situation and my intuition (and practical work) tells me this is the only solution for this physical situation.

If someone could give me a different and satisfying way of thinking why we reject complex solutions (even if only in the case I used) would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you were told to "reject" solutions just because they were imaginary, then you were either mis-informed or you mis-understood. One possible source of mis-understanding is that in a specific problem you might be *required* to find real valued solutions, and in that case you would definitely reject imaginary solutions. If for example you were asked for the rational solutions to $x^2 - 2 = 0$ then you would reject the solutions $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$; or if you asked for the positive solutions to $x^2 -2x - 3 = 0$ then you would reject the negative solution $x=-1$.

Comment: In your example, the beam is exactly the interval $[0,5]$.  Neither $1-i$ nor $1+i$ lies on the beam (in much the same way that $-1$ doesn't lie on the beam).  Hence there is s physical reason to reject those solutions---it has nothing to do with the fact that they are "imaginary" solutions.

Comment: @LeeMosher I understand that. What I actually don't understand is how to interpret the complex solutions here?

Comment: Okay got it. I have to imagine all physical situation immersed in complex spaces but to only consider solutions inside the domain of interest. Now I will have to think about how to extend complex domain to more than one imaginary unit, for dealing with more general problems taking 3d volumes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"If, suppose we are doing a calculation regarding a physical situation and some of the solutions at the end turn out to be "imaginary" and some are real then we reject the imaginary ones without even giving them a second thought just because they were imaginary (at least I was told to do like this)."
  **Who** told you to do this and what made you think it was "just because they were imaginary"?  And why do you think this was only because of the name "imaginary"?

If this was a physics or other science course, you might well be told that you could ignore "imaginary" solutions.  But that would be because certain values in science are defined, connected with measurements, so that they can only be real numbers, not because they don't like the name "imaginary".  And there are quantities in physics that [b]are[/b] complex numbers.

Comment: Yes. I agree many quantities are imaginary. I even mentioned one in my explanation above. What I was not able to think was how to interpret the complex solutions I got. Which I think would be solved if we consider the beam being immersed in the complex plane instead of real (seems obvious to me now). Now the problem is how to increase the dimensions of the complex plane to complex space to deal with 2d or 3d problems.  If you have any idea about this?